# cakePHP readonly field size

Tags: cakephp

I have the following bit of code

```
echo $this->Form->input('Users.failure', array ("label" => 'Reason Failed', 'id'=> 'ReasonAutoPop','size' => '100', 'readonly'=>'readonly'));
```

The field is auto-populated via javaScript. It has to be kept read-only as per customer specification, in certain conditions. The longest failure reason is 100 characters. I can only currently display 27 characters only. Is there a different way to set width/size for readonly fields?

Comment: Why is that Users.failure, and not User.failure (as per convention for models)? Sure, this is not an error at your end? Besides: the maxlength is specified by your db field lenght. You might want to raise that then.

Answer (score 0):

My tip:
Use a hidden read-only field, and mimic an input field - designed to your needs with `<P>` or `<PRE>`.

edit

---

```
echo $this->Form->input('Users.failure', array ("label" => 'Reason Failed', 'id'=> 'ReasonAutoPop','size' => '100', 'readonly'=>'readonly', 'type'=>'hidden'));
// since it's hidden, you shouldnt care about its size.
// now, add a css designed element.
echo "<p class='looks_like_an_input_field'>$value_of_Users.failure_element</p>";
```

is it clearer?

Comment: The readonly field needs to display, per spec. Care to explain as to what you mean by your suggestion?

Comment: I mean, if readonly is fixed and can't be done, it can't be done

Comment: The data will be shown, but using another element, to avoid the problems you have. it will be accessible as any